# Como chamar uma action assim que o Web API iniciar?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Estou estudando Web API e estou com dúvida sobre como chamar uma Action assim que eu clicar no botão play do Visual Studio.

Eu imagino que isso deva ser feito no método Main, da classe Program, mas não faço ideia de como fazer isso.

O objetivo final é fazer essa aplicação ser iniciada e, de tempos em tempos, ler os dados do banco de dados e enviá-los a um endpoint de outra API que ainda vou criar.

Por enquanto, estou nessa fase de fazer a aplicação iniciar chamando uma Action.

Informações adicionais:

- O projeto foi criado em Asp.NetCore 2.2
- Está rodando localmente: https://localhost:44366/

Mais para frente, vou usar o pacote Chroniton para fazer a leitura dos dados periodicamente.

Comment: Estranho sua pergunta porque isso seja mais claro ...

Comment: Não faz sentido uma WebAPI chamar uma action dela mesma... Mas você pode executar essa rotina no start da aplicação sim na startup

Comment: Virgilio Novic e @LeandroAngelo o que eu preciso é, assim que iniciar a API, ela leia os dados da tabela de tempos em tempos e os envie a um endpoint de outra API. E estou quebrando a cabeça para saber como isso deve ser feito.

Comment: @EvertonSolon De tempos em tempos? não me parece que isso seja adequado... pode ser o caso de criar uma outra aplicação com essa responsabilidade única.

Comment: @LeandroAngelo eu entendo o seu ponto do vista mas é o que o teste da empresa, na qual sou candidato, está pedindo. Entede? rsrs

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Nesse caso o melhor seria voce ter uma aplicacao console aplication (por exemplo) para fazer a leitura do banco, com essa aplicacao voce so precisa agenda-la no windows pra executar de tempos em tempos e chamar a API.

Se tiver pensando em rodar em cloud vc ja poderia partir pra uma solucao serveless (como o [Azure Functions](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/functions/?))

Comment: relendo o que a empresa pediu (em inglês), bate com o que você sugeriu de criar um console application para fazer a leitura do banco. Mas vou usar um pacote de faz o agendamento pela própria aplicação. Como trata-se de um teste para entrar na empresa e posso fazer em casa, então será algo simples. Agradeço muito a sua colaboração!

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar também o Hangfire para agendar a ação.
https://www.hangfire.io/

Basta instalar os pacotes e depois inserir a chamada ao `hangfire` para fazer o agendamento
Exemplo:

```
var jobId = BackgroundJob.Schedule(
    () => Console.WriteLine("Delayed!"),
    TimeSpan.FromDays(7));
```

Comment: Obrigado pela dica @Felipe Alexandre Miranda!!! Vi que esse pacote tem muito mais downloads que o Chroniton.